# Use @types/foo definitions with another module that exports (among others) the foo package?

Tags: typescript

Let's assume I have some module called 'foo'. This module does a lot of things and it also exports mongoose.

```js
// foo/index.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = {
  // ...lots of other things and:
  mongoose, 
}
```

I don't own this module so I cannot change it. The `foo` package does not expose any types!

In my personal TypeScript project I'm importing mongoose from `foo` like so:

```js
// some-file.ts

import { mongoose } from 'foo';

const carSchema = new mongoose.Schema( /* ... /* );

// etc ...
```

I have zero code completion and type checking at this point. How can I now install `@types/mongoose` and tell typescript that `{ mongoose } from 'foo'` should use these type definitions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. You can consider making a DefinitelyTyped package `@types/foo`.
2. You can make a `foo.d.ts` file anywhere in your repo (I use `src/lib/types/augments/foo.d.ts`), and then tell it that the module exports `mongoose` (note: `@types/mongoose` must be a real dependency, not a development dependency for this to work):

```js
import Mongoose from '@types/mongoose';

declare module 'foo' {
    export const mongoose: Mongoose;
}
```